# Calculate values based on conditions and add new rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following example dataframe:

```
first_column <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C")
second_column <- c("aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "bb", "bb", "cc", "cc", "cc")
third_column <- c("10", "12", "13", "15", "20", "21", "22", "24", "26")

df <- data.frame(first_column, second_column, third_column)
```

It looks like this:

```
first_column second_column third_column
            A            aa           10
            B            aa           12
            C            aa           13
            A            bb           15
            B            bb           20
            C            bb           21
            A            cc           22
            B            cc           24
            C            cc           26
```

For every category of the second column i want to calculate a new value for the category (A - B- C = D). I want the new dataframe to look like that:

```
first_column second_column third_column
            A            aa           10
            B            aa           12
            C            aa           13
            A            bb           15
            B            bb           20
            C            bb           21
            A            cc           22
            B            cc           24
            C            cc           26
            D            aa           -15   (10 - 12 - 13)
            D            bb           -26   (15 - 20 - 21)
            D            cc           -28   (22 - 24 - 26)
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? I'd prefer a solution with the dplyr library, if this would be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(second_column) %>% 
  summarise(first_column = "D", 
            third_column = third_column[first_column == "A"] - third_column[first_column == "B"] + third_column[first_column == "C"]) %>% 
  bind_rows(df, .)

   first_column second_column third_column
1             A            aa           10
2             B            aa           12
3             C            aa           13
4             A            bb           15
5             B            bb           20
6             C            bb           21
7             A            cc           22
8             B            cc           24
9             C            cc           26
10            D            aa          -15
11            D            bb          -26
12            D            cc          -28
```

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response. I'd unfortunately need an option where it's based on conditions (like: if "aa" then A - B - C). Do you also know a solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean? can you reflect that in your question?

Comment: I get an error message when i want to edit the question. I try to explain it: The example I did is very simplified. In my dataset, the first column doesn’t always have the same order. Also, I have about 10 columns, but I just want to filter in one column by category and then do the calculations on several columns (eg. fourth_column <- c("11", "13", "14", "16", "21", "22", "23", "25", "27"; also A - B - C).

Comment: What about this edit?

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant! Thank you Maël. 
Is there any chance you also know how i could address the columns by index? (Only within the summarise function necessary..).